# Derivative of $y=\tan(3)e^x$,

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If, $y=\tan(3)e^x$,

wouldn't the derivative be $y\;'=\sec^2(3)e^x \times e^x$? The outer function times the inner function, using the chain rule? The answer key gives the derivative as $y=e^x \tan 3$ and I don't understand this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\tan(3)$ is just a constant so the function is of the form $$y = Ce^x$$ and its derivative is simply $$y' = \tan(3)e^x$$

The product rule is not needed here.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* apply the product rule,
but since $\tan(3)$
is a constant,
its derivative is zero,
so the
$(\tan(3))'$
term goes away.

Answer (score 2):

$\tan(3)$ is a constant; hence the derivative is simply $\tan(3)e^x$.

You're probably misreading it as something else.

Answer (score 2):

$\tan(3) = -0.14$, it is a constant. You just need to differentiate $e^x$.